# How should I implement a PromQL query which generates a report of all the Http Api endpoints where the error percentage is > 0.2%

Tags: prometheus

I am instrumenting a prometheus counter metric called 
"http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status" which contains 2 labels as "http_endpoint" and "http_status". I would like to use this counter to generate a PromQL query to generate a report to track which api endpoints have errors such that the error percentage is > 0.2%.

I have structured the query as :

```
   100*(sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status{http_status="500"}[5m])) by 
   (http_api_endpoint) / sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status[5m])) by 
   (http_api_endpoint)) > 0.2 and 
   sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status[5m])) by (http_api_endpoint)) > 
   0
```

My question is, instead of using the rate function, if I sum directly on the counters, would that be incorrect?

For e.g.

```
   100*(sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status{http_status="500"}[5m])) by 
   (http_api_endpoint) / sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status[5m])) by 
   (http_api_endpoint)) > 0.2 and 
   sum(rate(http_requests_by_endpoint_and_status[5m])) by (http_api_endpoint)) > 
   0
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, instead of using the rate function, if I sum directly on the counters, would that be incorrect?

Depends what you mean by incorrect. It will give you the error rate since your server started, which is very likely not what you want. And if you have more than one server, then the ones that started longer ago will weigh more than the ones that started more recently. In particular, to take an extreme example, if one server started 500 days ago and has served no errors and the other server just restarted and is serving errors only, it will take a full day of errors before your alert fired.

Also, you don't need the `and sum(...) > 0` condition at the end. If the counter (or its rate over 5 minutes) is zero, then the result for that set of labels will be `NaN` and it will not be `> 0.2`.